# Prove that a set is linearly independent in the vector space of all functions of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

I want to solve the following exercise

Let $V=F( \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})$ be the vector space of all functions of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Prove that $\left\lbrace{f_1,f_2,f_3}\right\rbrace$ is linearly independent in $V$, where $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are given by: $$f_1(x)=1, f_2(x)=e^{ix}=\cos x+i \sin x, f_3(x)=e^{-ix}$$ for each real x.

What I do is to consider three elements of the set of complex numbers $(a+bi), (c+di), (e+hi)$ such that

$$(a+bi)(1)+(c+di)(\cos x+i \sin x)+(e+hi)(e^{-ix})=0$$

Now, I don't know what else to do after posing the above equality, any help?

Comment: Hint: if they are linearly independent, then they have to be in each point you calculate them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\Bbb C$ such that $\alpha f_1+\beta f_2+\gamma f_3=0$. Then:

- $\alpha f_1(0)+\beta f_2(0)+\gamma f_3(0)=0$; in other words, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0$.
- $\alpha f_1(\pi)+\beta f_2(\pi)+\gamma f_3(\pi)=0$; in other words,
  $\alpha-\beta-\gamma=0$
- $\alpha f_1\left(\frac\pi2\right)+\beta f_2\left(\frac\pi2\right)+\gamma f_3\left(\frac\pi2\right)=0$; in other words, $\alpha+\beta i-\gamma i=0$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating $0=c_1f_1+c_2f_2+c_3f_3$ gives $0=c_2f_2-c_3f_3$.

Adding the first to the latter and differentiating once more gives

$0=c_2f_2 \implies c_2=0$.

Similarly,

$0=c_1f_1+c_3f_3 \implies 0=c_3f_3 \implies c_3=0$.

So $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$, and $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ is a linearly independent set in $V$.

Answer (score 0):

[Equivalent to the answer by "undefined"] The [Wronskian determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) of the three functions is $-2i$ which is not zero.  Thus, the three functions are linearly independent.

---

These functions are analytic, so the converse is also true: Wronkian determinant zero implies linearly dependent.  But we do not need this direction here.